# How to create / login to a user in CockroachDB

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

I have created a local cockroachDB using:

```
cockroach sql --insecure
```

and when I am trying to create a user using:

```
create user 'name' with password 'password';
```

I get a error:

```
ERROR: setting or updating a password is not supported in insecure mode
```

Anyone know a workaround for this or how I can login to the admin user that already exists.

I managed to solve my issue by just using the root user instead but I would still like to know a good solution or fix for this problem for anyone else having this issue in the future since I could not find any way to login to a user or anyone who had a solution for this issue.

I created a cockroachDB in DBeaver in hopes of this insecure issue would not appear but it had the same outcome.

Comment: Have you tried to create it without the insecure flag ?

Comment: Yes, and when I do that it does not work and it recommends me to create it using the insecure flag

Answer (score 1):

As per the CockroachDB official document, Password creation is supported only in secure clusters. To create user with password in CockroachDB you need to follow below steps.

Step 1:- Create a secure cluster. You can refer this official CockroachDB document to [create secure cluster](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/secure-a-cluster.html).

Step 2:- Start secure cluster to run CockroachDB in secure cluster.

Step 3:- Create a user in secure cluster. You can refer this official CockroachDB document to [create user](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/create-user.html) with password.

I have successfully created user with password in CockroachDB with above steps.